# Named step blocks in SpecFlow

Tags: selenium, webdriver, specflow

If someone knows, how to use repeating bunches of steps in Specflow, i.e. I need to check several pages, which contain some portion of same elements.

Something like this:

```
When I open page Page1
Then <do_something>
And I check button 3
When I open page Page2
Then <do_something>
And I check Textfield1
When I open page Page3
Then <do_something>
And I check button 4

<do_something>:
And I check button 1
And I check button 2
```

As if I have buttons 1 and 2 on each page, and something else in addition, but I dont want to write steps for buttons 1 and 2 for each page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
Scenario Outline: Pages
    Given I am on page <page>
    When I click on "button 1"
    And I click on "button 2"
    Then something will happen

Examples: 
    | page  |
    | page1 |
    | page2 |
    | page3 |
```

Comment: Thought about that. But examples will simply do similar actions for every page, I cannot add specific actions for every page in this.

Answer (score 0):

Note that anything you place in the Examples table, in the same row as your example, will be used in the context of that example. So say, you want to do specific actions on every page, add this to the row of that page. (@marcel, sorry for copying your code, but I couldn't post this as a commend and format it a.f.a.i.k.)

```
Scenario Outline: Pages
    Given I am on page <page>
    When I click on "button 1"
    And I do "<action1>"
    And I do "<action2>"
    Then something will happen

Examples: 
    | page  | action1 | action 2 |
    | page1 | action  | action   |
    | page2 | action  | action   |
    | page3 | action  | action   |
```